# Numbers inputted each month but then don't appear after that (across month) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Current SQL fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1163a/1

I am looking for a total of how many items were added in a specific month but then a total of how many were never a part of an order in the months after that.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
ItemNo varchar(10)
,DateAdded date
);

CREATE TABLE Order1 (
OrderNo int,
ItemNo varchar(10),
OrderDate date
);

INSERT INTO Item (ItemNo, DateAdded)
VALUES ('111', '01-01-17'),
('222', '03-01-17'),
('333', '05-01-17'),
('444', '06-02-17'),
('555', '10-02-17'),
('666', '20-02-17');

INSERT INTO Order1 (ItemNo, OrderDate)
VALUES ('111', '10-01-17'),
('111', '20-02-17'),
('222', '07-05-17'),
('333', '20-01-17'),
('333', '08-03-17'),
('444', '25-01-17');
```

Currently i have:

```
SELECT  
-- b.OrderDate,
    A.DateAdded,
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.ItemNo) AS [Items Added],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ItemNo IS NULL THEN 1 END) as [Items Never Ordered],
    COUNT(A.ItemNo) OVER (Partition by MONTH(B.OrderDate))
    FROM    Item a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT OrderDate FROM Order1) b
    LEFT JOIN Order1 c
    ON a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo
    AND b.OrderDate = c.OrderDate 

    GROUP BY A.DateAdded, b.OrderDate
```

The result i am looking for is:

```
| DateAdded | Items Added | Items Never Ordered |
|-----------|-------------|---------------------|
|    Feb-17 |           3 |                   2 |
|    Jan-17 |           3 |                   0 |
```

Can anyone advise me on the best way too approach this? Thanks

This is not a duplicate - there were no answers to the previous question because of date issue

Comment: Newer store date as string!.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed edit made

Comment: You are added items `111,222,333` in `Jan-17` and ordered `111,333,444` but `Items Never Ordered` is `0` ? I missed anything?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed I guess the item doesn't need to be ordered in the same month it was added. But it's strange to order 444 before it was added.

Comment: @Peter, still i think the values are wrong. Added 3 item and ordered 3 items(may another items). Suppose if ordered more than 3, then what will be the value of `Items Never Ordered`? `-1`? OP have to explain the logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing values between 2 tables across month field SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155170/comparing-values-between-2-tables-across-month-field-sql-server)

Comment: A duplicate of your own question.  Not cool.

Comment: @Paparazzi the last question wasnt resolved due to the date issue

Comment: Still a duplicate and still a varchar

Comment: @Paparazzi no its not

Comment: @Paparazzi This site is here to help each other, not moan about unanswered duplicate questions. whats your problem

Comment: People like you that spam the site is my problem. There are rules.  It is an exact copy other than the format of the date which you could have edited.  You were told early on need date and your response was you did not control the date format.  The accepted answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Paparazzi then why do people tell me to start a new question as opposed to editing an old one? And the answer to this question does exactly what i need

Comment: I think you got what you deserved.   Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like pointed out by Abdul. Always use the right datatype, a date is not a string.
If you want your data grouped by month, than group by year and month, not by date.
Your cross join did not make sense to me, I left it out.

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    ItemNo varchar(10)
   ,DateAdded date
);

CREATE TABLE Order1 (
    OrderNo int,
    ItemNo varchar(10),
    OrderDate date
);

INSERT INTO Item (ItemNo, DateAdded)
VALUES ('111', '2017-01-01'),
('222', '2017-01-03'),
('333', '2017-01-05'),
('444', '2017-02-06'),
('555', '2017-02-10'),
('666', '2017-02-20');

INSERT INTO Order1 (ItemNo, OrderDate)
VALUES ('111', '2017-01-10'),
('111', '2017-02-20'),
('222', '2017-05-07'),
('333', '2017-01-20'),
('333', '2017-03-08'),
('444', '2017-01-25');

SELECT  
    datepart(year,A.DateAdded) Year,datepart(Month,A.DateAdded) Month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.ItemNo) AS [Items Added],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ItemNo IS NULL THEN 1 END) as [Items Never Ordered]
FROM Item a
LEFT JOIN Order1 c ON a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo
GROUP BY datepart(year,A.DateAdded),datepart(Month,A.DateAdded)
```